# Where to place libqca2 plugin in Windows?

Tags: plugins, qt4

I've successfully built libqca2 and qca-ossl2 plugin , but where should I place qca-ossl2.dll ?

If I place the dll in the same folder with my application , it just tell me "XXX is not supported" , which indicates the plugin is not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a folder named "**crypto**" in your application folder, and put the plugin dll there.

The OpenSSL dlls (libeay32.dll and libssl32.dll) should be copied directly in the application folder.